# How do I search Full text with partial matches?

Tags: php, mysql, database, full-text-search

I have a table, with not many rows, and neither many columns. I am doing a Full text search on 3 columns.

My code is

```
$search_input = trim($_GET['s']);
$search = mysql_real_escape_string($search_input);
$search = '+'.str_replace(' ', '* +', $search).'*';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE   
        MATCH(def, pqr, xyz) AGAINST ('$search' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

I can correctly search for terms like **abcdefgh**, which are present as **... abcdefgh ...**.

But I am receiving empty set with search terms like **abc**, where in table entry is present something like **abc-123**, and also terms like **abcdefghs**. (notice this is plural of above)

Clearly I need to implement partial search, or something like that.
But how do I implement such a search? Any better way to do a entire table search on user input?

Do mention anything I am doing incorrectly.

**EDIT** : By adding * after each word, now I am able to also search for **abcde**, but above problems remains.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you don't get results for 3 letter combinations? If so, you might be hitting the mysql index length (which is usually set to 3)

More info here - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html

Comment: Yes, looks like I am facing this trouble. BTW I think the page you referred, says default is 4 chars not 3. And I cannot touch this length.

Comment: Sorry, yes. Looking at the docs, setting the `ft_min_word_len` option in your conf file might help.